# LINQ - Condition with .Contains() is not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I cannot seem to get the desirable filtered result from my query.

Data

```cs
public class fdp_1115
{
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public string Number{ get; set; }
    public string Type{ get; set; }
} 

List<fdp_1115> fdpList = new List<fdp_1115> 
{
    new fdp_1115 { Id = "1", Number = "Lot123", Type = "D14MWT" },
    new fdp_1115 { Id = "2", Number = "Lot123", Type = "E12WBC7W1" }
};
List<string> searchValues = new List<string> { "MLE12WBC7W1 A R" };
```

LINQ:

```cs
var LocType = fdpList.FirstOrDefault(d => searchValues.Any(s => d.Type.Contains(s)));
    
if (LocType != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Matching record found:");
    Console.WriteLine($"Id: {LocType.Id}, Number: {LocType.Number}, Type: {LocType.Type}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No matching records found.");
}
```

The result I wanted is:

> Matching record found:
>
> Id: 2, Number: Lot123, Type: E12WBC7W1

But I got `"No matching records found."` which indicates that `LocType == null`.

I already tried trimming and ignoring case sensitive:

```cs
var LocType = fdpList.FirstOrDefault(d => searchValues.Any(s => d.Type.Contains(s.Trim().Replace(" ", ""))));
var LocType = fdpList.FirstOrDefault(d => searchValues.Any(s => d.Type.Contains(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

But still no luck. Any idea how do I match "MLE12WBC7W1 A R" with "E12WBC7W1"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current logic checks whether there is any object with `Type` value that contains the value for each string in the `searchValues` array.

From your requirement:

You want to filter the object that fulfills there is any string in `searchValues` containing the value of `Type`.

Thus it should be:

```cs
var LocType = fdpList.FirstOrDefault(d => searchValues.Any(s => s.Contains(d.Type)));
```

Comment: So that's means I have been using .Contains on the searchValues instead of my db collection list. Dang, I feel stupid. Your solution work perfectly, I will mark yours as answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have your contains the other way around.

`d.Type = "E12WBC7W1"`

and

`s = "MLE12WBC7W1 A R"`

Then `"E12WBC7W1"` does not `Contains` `"MLE12WBC7W1 A R"`

It is the other way around.

```
var LocType = fdpList.FirstOrDefault(d => searchValues.Any(s => s.Contains(d.Type)));
```